# Сайт не работает с MySQL во время выполнения скрипта, записывающего в базу MySQL. Как исправить?

Tags: mysql, apache, apache2

Есть чужой скрип, загружающий данные в интернет-магазин из локального xml-файла.
Всё работает на VPS с BitrixVM 7.5 (nginx, apache, mysql 5.7.35-38, php 5.6, 2 ядра, 2 гига)
Сайт в целом летает.

*Но есть проблема: во время работы того скрипта вообще не открываются страницы сайта.*

*Но в тоже время:*

- На сайте быстро открывает статика через nginx
- Быстро работают файлы php, не использующие базу данных (phpinfo
  моментально выводится)

*Результаты моих исследований:*

- Команда mysql `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` показывает, что висит один процесс. Но если его убить, то  страницы сайта всё равно не отрываются.
- Перезагрузка mysqld не помогает - страницы сайта не открываются.
- После перезапуска mysqld apache начинает загружать процессор на 25%. И невозможно выполнить `service httpd restart` - висит.
  Но если сделать `kill` процесса с apache, то всё сразу отвисает (и не надо трогать mysqld).
- По совету коллеги я посмотрел нагрузку на диск с помощью `iotop -oka` Этот показатель в среднем колеблется от 500 до 3000 K/s, очень редко поднимается на секунду до 6000 К/s
- Действующие переменные MySQL в pastebin: https://pastebin.com/VYE02kXj

Автор скрипта сказал, что нужно настраивать хостинг. Но не дал конкретных инструкций.

И у меня чувство, что залочены таблицы или в настройках хостинга запрещено несколько параллельных обращений к базе данных.

Куратор тега MySQL в аналогичном русскоязычном сервисе тоже считает, что дело в "лочках". И считает это интересной и обширной темой. Спасибо ему за это.

*Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли настроить MySQL, чтобы наполнение сайта скриптом не блокировало его работу?*

Comment: Кстати, проблема проявляется только на VPS и на локальных сборках WAMP. На различных виртуальных хостингах всё работает как надо. Я что-то упускаю уже долгие годы. Но не могу понять что именно.